# How do I restart the network or ask the system to seek a refresh IP from the DHCP?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, minix

I'm running a Minix using VirtualBox. Minix is set to use the DHCP. And the network adapter is using a bridged connection<sup>*</sup>.

When I last saved the state of the machine its IP was *192.168.1.11* (`ifconfig`) and was connected to *wlan0* (VirtualBox network settings). When I resumed the machine I changed the network adapter to *eth0* -- the DHCP on this network<sup>*</sup> hands-out IP in the range *192.168.0.X*-- but the IP that the system is assuming is, for obvious reasons, *192.168.1.11* which of course can't be reached. For say, ssh-ing.

I know Minix conforms with the POSIX standards. But like in Ubuntu (Linux) I couldn't use `service networking restart` nor could I find anything under `/etc` that could provide a hint. Of course I could use something like `ifconfig -h 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500`. But I want to get the IP from the DHCP.

**Question:**

- How can I restart (command) the network dev/manager in Minix? (Assuming that way I could get a new IP)
- How can I request (command) a new IP from the DHCP?

<sup>*please excuse/correct my (if any) technically inaccurate description.</sup>

Comment: *"for obvious reasons"* -- Are you sure the reason is just self-evident?  Do you believe the minix kernel is making this mistake, or is it some userland application?  It's implied here that by "saved state" you mean, while the system was running (as opposed to cleanly shut down).   It's also implicit that you are using some kind of dhcp client (normal linux networking does).  If both those implications are true, the issue is with the userland dhcp client.  You need to restart that.

Comment: Isn't there any docs for that?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I maybe outright wrong because I'm new at this. Since I have read a fair deal of material on micro- and macro-kernels so I can assume it's a userland application and not the kernel's mistake. I'll have to find DHCP client process since the first answer is yes and the second one could be yes (not sure) because I choose DHCP during installation. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Google and DDG failed be at it.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: The Minix docs I just quickly scanned through indeed don't seem to be very verbose on that.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: Just curious, are you runing minix as part of some university task or there's some other reason?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda It's just that I'm curious to use and explore it. See how far I can go with it and if I could really make it a system of choice. Get Firefox and other funky stuff to work on it. See if there are any appreciable performance hits because of the frequent run-level switches. And hey Linux's initial development was done on Minix, you ought to know something about it. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: Yep, I heard a bit about the Linux beginnings, although I must admit I see much more fun around Gentoo, OpenEmbedded and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](http://wiki.minix3.org/UsersGuide/NetworkConfiguration) and man pages leads me to believe that you should use [`netconf`](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/html8/netconf.html).  According to its manual page, something like:

```
netconf -a
```

and then answering any interactive questions, likely does what you wan.  You're existing configuration exists in:

```
/etc/inet.conf
```

It seems you can also get [dhcpd](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/html8/dhcpd.html) to print its current view of the world with:

```
dhcpd -q
```

And it further seems that you can restart all network services with

```
/etc/rs.inet
```

Note that this is just from reading the pretty sparse documentation and poking around the system for a few minutes, but hopefully it gives you some places to continue to investigate. I would also try reading the boot man page and then looking at the various rc scripts it calls on system init.  The /etc/rs.inet command above is used in /usr/etc/rc by the service command, which also has a restart action that might be interesting to you.

Comment: *"You might have to reboot for the changes to take effect."*

Comment: Added some more that I found that might help.

Comment: Deleted the other answer as it was a small subset of this one.